# Should and can I connect my Facebook page for my website to my website's like button?

Tags: facebook-like

It seems I have 2 pages to "like" on Facebook for my website: 1) The Facebook page for my website and 2) The actual URL of my website which is a different page than for my Facebook page. And even a third option 3) The URL to my FB app which has a third address.

I don't know which of these three that I should promote when I want users to "like" my webapp or is it even possible to make users "like" the Facebook page instead of the URL to the website? Currently the FB page ("www.facebook.com/mybrandname") has many more likes than the actual URL to the webapp ("www.brandname.com"). So I thought that I might "consolidate" the likes to just one page and in that case, which one should I use to accumulate likes?

Comment: what do you mean by `to make users "like" the Facebook page **instead of** the URL to the website? `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my view, you should go for the Facebook page. That's where users would be looking for 'how many likes' you got.